# Where can I see Twitter replies to me?

Tags: twitter

Where can I see Twitter replies to me? Clicking on my user name does nothing. I've scoured the Twitter page and can find no replies button or even a Help button. I have been trying for some months to get to use Twitter but so far have been unable to get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about *@replies* or *direct messages*?

From the iteration of the Twitter web client I'm looking at...

- @replies are under the `@ Connect` menu (you might want to click on `> Mentions` to be a little more focused)
- direct messages are under the "gear" menu